# Finding Height of a node in an AVL Tree for Balance Factor calculation

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

AVL tree is a binary search tree that is balanced i.e height = O(log(n)). This is achieved by making sure every node follows the AVL tree property:

> Height of the left subtree(LST) - Height of the right subtree(RST) is
> in the range [-1, 0, 1]

where Height(LST) - Height(RST) is called Balance factor(BF) for a given node.

The height of the node is usually defined as, "length of the path(#edges) from that node to the deepest node"
eg:
[image: Height Example]

By this definition, **height of leaf is 0.**
But almost everytime while discussing AVL trees, people consider **height of the leaf to be 1**.

My question is, *can we take the height of leaf to be 0*? This will make following BSTs also AVL trees, right?

[image]

Height concept confuses me because of these articles:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-nodes-in-an-avl-tree-with-given-height/
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/minimum-number-of-nodes-in-an-avl-tree-with-given-height-using-cplusplus

Firstly, they start the height with 0.
Then they say, *minimum number of nodes required for avl tree of height 2 to be 4* BUT if height is starting with zero, I can have the following AVL trees too, right?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By this definition, height of leaf is 0.

This is correct.

> BUT if height is starting with zero, I can have the following AVL trees too, right?
>
> [image]

No, the parent of the leaf has height 1, as the path from that node to the leaf has 1 edge.

So it should be:

```
              O  -- height 2, balance factor 2
             /
            O  -- height 1, balance factor 1
           /
          O  -- height 0
```

The balance factor of the root is 2 because the height of its left subtree is 1 and that of its right subtree is -1 (!). Note that if a single node has height 0, then an empty tree has height -1. This is also what is mentioned in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology):

> The height of a node is the length of the longest downward path to a leaf from that node. [...] The root node has depth zero, leaf nodes have height zero, and a tree with only a single node (hence both a root and leaf) has depth and height zero. Conventionally, an empty tree (tree with no nodes, if such are allowed) has height −1.

And so these are not valid AVL trees: they need to be rebalanced.

Comment: I agree the heights you have written are correct, but since BF(balance factor) = H(LST) - H(RST), shouldn't the BF for root be H(LST) - H(RST) = 1 - 0 = 1?

Comment: No, it would be 1 - (-1) = 2. See addition to answer.

Comment: Alright, so the height of an empty tree is -1. That's where I was confused!